# ISA Related Questions: Is our network ISA-Enabled?

Tags: isa-server, web-services

We have a product that uses Web Services. On our primary testing here on our local site, the product seems to be functioning well. When the product was deployed on another site, it went crazy with the infamous ISA HTTP 407 error.

So I have a couple of questions regarding ISA:

1. How do you know if a network is ISA enabled?
2. Can a Windows Machine be affected by the ISA server even if it is not joined to a domain?
3. Since the web service is on the SAME MACHINE as the product, is there a way to tell the machine to not process the HTTP traffic through the ISA Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of ISA? And what do you exactly mean by "ISA enabled network"?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISA Server is a firewall/proxy, so it can only affect external connections, and only if it's your gateway and/or if you use it as a proxy; it should definitely ***not*** affect connections from one machine to itself.

Have a look at the proxy settings in Internet Explorer; is your ISA server configured there? If yes, try disabling it or adding an exclusion for *localhost*, *127.0.0.1*, your computer's host name and/or its IP address.

Comment: Is it possible that a machine will use the ISA server even if the proxy setting in IE is blank?

Comment: For Internet connections, yes: ISA will always act as a web proxy when you use it as a gateway, even if you don't explicitly configure IE to use it. For local connections, this could only happen if you have the ISA Firewall Client installed, which hijacks the whole Windows networking stack in order to forward everything through ISA; but it shouldn't anyway affect loopback connections.

Comment: By use it as a gateway, do you mean the gateway in the NIC properties?

Comment: Yes. I mean having ISA as your gateway/firewall to the Internet.

Comment: Solved our problem by detaching the machine to the network.